# CKEditor Plugin 'save' (egeloen / ivoryckeditor) in Symfony 3 not showing the save button

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-3.3, ckeditor4.x, symfony3.x

I successfully installed and integrated the CKEditor (4.7.3) in my Symfony 3.3.10 project using the ckeditor-bundle from egeloen (ivoryckeditor).
I am now trying to get the ["Save" Plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/save) to work.

I copied the plugin folder into my web-folder.
This is my test configuration in config.yml

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    inline: true
    autoload: false
    async: false
    configs:
        ckeditor_config_1:
            toolbar: [ [ "Save", "Cut", "Copy" ] ]
            extraPlugins: "save"
    plugins:
        save:
            path:       "/bundles/ivoryckeditor/plugins/save/"
            filename:   "plugin.js"
```

Thats how I create the ckeditor form to pass to twig for rendering:

```
$ckeditForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('ckedit_form', CKEditorType::class, $content, array(
    'label' => false,
    'config' => array(
        'config_name' => 'ckeditor_config_1',
        'inline' => true,
    ),
))->getForm();
```

Unfortunately the "Save" Button is not showing up.
Any ideas about the cause of the button not showing up are very welcome.

Comment: Have you put your plugin folder  to src/ressources/public ? Then execute assets:install so Symfony create the plugin folder in web directory

Comment: @Mz1907 I just copied the save plugin to web/bundles/ivoryckeditor/plugins. The ivoryckeditor bundle was installed like you proposed but from vendor/egeloen/ckeditor-bundle/ I did not yet try to explicitly install the save plugin the same way also. How would I do that? In app/Resources I don't have anything related to the bundle or plugin yet.

Comment: Can you install it directly in vendor ? In a past projet I had to install a plugin directly in vendor ... maybe this info could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - The save plugin is just not working in inline mode. Could be documented somewhere - couldn't find any hint to that...

Comment: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_savedata-section-the-save-plugin